# Firebase storage rules - Unexpected 'userId'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm trying to set a rule, in firebase for storage, where only the authenticated user can write his avatar image called avatar

This is [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start) example:

```
// Grants a user access to a node matching their user ID
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Files look like: "user/<UID>/path/to/file.txt"
    match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

and these are my rules defined in storage.rules file:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }

    match /images/{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024
                    && request.resource.contentType.matches("image/.*")
                    && request.resource.contentType == resource.contentType
    }

    match /images/user-{userId}/avatar.* {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

When I deploy the error thrown is

> [E] 13:25 - Unexpected 'userId'

I can't find anything else in the docs telling me how to defined this userId. The docs specify it and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could it be that wildcards are not allowed as partial matches, and only work as a full match at a location?  So, not `/images/user-{userId}`, but instead `/images/{userId}`

Comment: I think you meant to `/images/user/{userId}/avatar` not `/images/user-{userId}/avatar` , aren't you ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like both commenters said the syntax doesn't allow "folders" with -

So you must opt for a structure like

```
/images/user/{userId}
```

making the rule like:

```
match /images/user/{userId}/avatar.* {
  allow read;
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```